# Reverse array content?

Tags: iphone, arrays, sdk, reverse, mailcore

I am populating a table view with information, but would like it to be populated in reverse, so that any newly added cells (new email messages) would appear on the top, not the bottom.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MailCell";

    MailCell *cell = (MailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MailCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        // SLICK
        // Anything that should be the same on EACH cell should be here.

        UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:15.0/255.0 green:140.0/255.0 blue:198.0/255.0 alpha:1];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.messageText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        cell.messageText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    // Extract Data

    // Use the message object instead of the multiple arrays.

    CTCoreMessage *message = [[self allMessages] objectAtIndex:row];

    // Sender

    CTCoreAddress *sender = [message sender];
    NSString *senderName = [sender name];

    // Subject

    NSString *subject = [message subject];
    if ([subject length] == 0)
    {
        subject = @"(No Subject)";
    }

    // Body

    BOOL isPlain = YES;
    NSString *body = [message bodyPreferringPlainText:&isPlain];
    body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
    body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@" "];

    // Populate Cell

    [[cell nameText] setText:senderName];
    [[cell subjectField] setText:subject];
    [[cell messageText] setText:body];

    if ([message isUnread])
    {
        UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:15.0/255.0 green:140.0/255.0 blue:198.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.nameText.textColor = myColor;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.nameText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    return cell;

}
```

How I am loading the array:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)allMessages
{
    if (_allMessages == nil)
    {
        _allMessages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _allMessages;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pulling from NSArray Index `[indexPath row]` meaning you are starting at index 0 and going to n.  Which means you are not in reverse order.  You need to reverse your array first.  A simple way would be:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSArray *allMessages = [self allMessages];
    NSArray* reversedMessages = [[allMessages reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
}
```

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you can do:

```
CTCoreMessage *message = [reversedMessages objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please post that code into my existing code, as I don't exactly know what to pull from that array. If you want, just tell me where to put (or what to replace) and I will mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You need to do this outside your cellForRowAtIndexPath method so this doesn't happen every time a cell loads, maybe in your viewWillAppear.  You will want to do it with your allMessages array, check edit.

Comment: Ok, that will work what what I told you, you will need to put it in NSArray not NSMutableArray, but can put it back into MuteableArray after you reverse it.

Comment: Problem, everything else is also not reversed, like the subject, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to do the same process with all of your data arrays to maintain the correct order

Comment: Got it! Could you help me out with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180313/filter-out-double-space

Comment: Please mark this question answered, I will look at the other one as well