# Filter out double space

Tags: iphone, string, sdk

I am using the following code to filter out line breaks, etc., and replace them with spaces. Then, I am using another line to take that double space and replace it with only one space, but it still looks like there is a double space.

What am I doing wrong?

```
NSString *body = [message bodyPreferringPlainText:&isPlain];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@"\n"];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" "];
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNX6O.png

**EDIT**: I think I have found my problem, this only happens when the message is formatted like so:

```
Hello,

How are you doing?

Thanks!
```

But not when like this:

```
Hello,
How are you doing?
Thanks!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the string look like in that example image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out, with the help of GoZoner, that this is the code I needed:

```
NSString *body = [message bodyPreferringPlainText:&isPlain];
    body = [[body componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
             [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]
            componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
    body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly different approach.  Split the string by 'whitespace' and then rebuild the string.  Like this:

```
body = [[body componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
               [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]
            componentsJoinedByString: " "];
```

The specific problem that you are having is the following.  You start with:

```
Hello,

How are you doing?

Thanks!
```

Which as a string is `"Hello,\r\n\r\nHow are you doing?\r\n\r\nThanks"`.  You then transform, step by step as:

```
  "Hello,\n\n\n\nHow are you doing?\n\n\n\nThanks"     #\r becomes \n
  "Hello,    How are you doing?    Thanks"             #\n becomes ' ' (four of them)
  "Hello,  How are you doing?  Thanks"                 #'  ' becomes ' ' (four become two)
```

Use what I suggest, it is the best solution.  If you don't like that, just replace `'\r'` with `''`.